# Number conversion problem with the Google speech to text service

Tags: google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

We are having some problems with the Google speech to text service with one number (until now):

The number ends with ...35984778 and we are becoming ...35984**526**. The last 3 numbers are simply wrong. The spoken language is German.

The problem can be reproduced with the following steps:

- The user gives his phone number ...35984778 over the phone. This data is sent to the Google speech to text API.
- The Google speech to text service delivers ...35984**526**.

Other numbers work properly with endings like ...09778.

Here are some lines from the log files of the application:

```
...
{"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397981946,"msg":"starting with the following Google stream recognition options:","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"Goo gleRecognizeStream","config":{"encoding":"MULAW","sampleRateHertz":8000,"languageCode":"de-DE","profanityFilter":true,"speechContexts":[{"phrases":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]}]},"singleUtterance":true,"interimResults ":true,"verbose":true,"v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397981946,"msg":"starting session with sessionID 8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":30,"time":1588397981947,"msg":"...: The speech recognition session started.","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397985083,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397985278,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397985677,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397985877,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397985982,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397986383,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397986986,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397987085,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397987481,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397987778,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397988381,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397988577,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397988674,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397988680,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397989275,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397989875,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397990375,"msg":"received interim result","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":30,"time":1588397990947,"msg":"...: Received a transcription with a code unit length of 13 and a confidence score of 0.9190642237663269","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":" 8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397990948,"msg":"onRecognitionStop","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":30,"time":1588397990948,"msg":"...: The speech recognition session ended.","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397990948,"msg":"ended","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","sessionID":"8a3f07ca-4351-4e5d-b8c8-bcddc10468f9","name":"GoogleRecognizeStream","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397990952,"msg":"session closed","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":30,"time":1588397990954,"msg":"...: Received a request to start a speech recognition session.","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","v":1} {"pid":12,"hostname":"","level":20,"time":1588397995351,"msg":"session closed","name":"SpeechToTextAdapter","v":1}
...
```

This problem can be reproduced with an android mobile phone too. One of my colleagues did the test with her mobile phone and the same problem did occur. This test was made only with a mobile phone and not over the application where the Google speech to text service was integrated (as described above).